# I need help choosing and printing text in PYGTK

Tags: python, pygtk

I am trying to make a program that looks like the one below.

[Image](http://www1.ucc.on.ca/GEO/MrHoel/ics3u/tests/tux.png)

I that file is called Tux image.png and i have another called File to use.txt that looks like this

Microsoft
Apple
HP
Dell
Linux
Blackberry

I need to make the program appear like the one above by choosing the word Linux and printing it under the image.Here is the code that I have now.

```
# two underscores
Class tux:
    def __init__(self):
        win = gtk.Window( )
        img  = gtk.Image( )
        img.set_from_file(“Tux image.png”)
        win.add(img)
        win.show_all( )
        win.connect(‘destroy’,gtk.main_quit)


tux( )
gtk.main( )
```

I only need help with the importing of the document and printing the name at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need, but you can read the use.txt file like this:

```
fileobj = open("use.txt")
file_content = fileobj.read()
```

'file_content' should now contain:

```
Microsoft Apple HP Dell Linux Blackberry
```

You can split them in a list:

```
choices = file_content.split()
```

After that you could use gtk.ComboBox to display a combobox with choices.

Still not sure if this is what you want.

**EDIT:**

Adding a combo and a label:

```
class Tux(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tux, self).__init__()
        combobox = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
        combobox.connect("changed", self.on_changed)
        for choice in choices:
            combobox.append_text(choice)
        self.add(combobox)
        self.label = gtk.Label("No selection")
        self.add(self.label)
        img = gtk.Image( )
        img.set_from_file(“Tux image.png”)
        self.add(img)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

def on_changed(self, widget):
    self.label.set_label(widget.get_active_text())


Tux()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: I need to choose and print Linux in a label do you know how to do that

Comment: @Liam Yorkville: I just edited my answer. I didn't test the code myself but it should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
1- Load the image file into a Pixbuff, draw the text on it, and show it in the window, that is the hard way.
2- Add a `gtk.Fixed` into the window, and add both `gtk.Image` (loaded from file) and `gtk.Label` (including the text) to that `gtk.Fixed` widget, given specific location for text (for example x=300, y=750 here). Something like this:

```
class TuxWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        ####
        image = gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_file('Tux image.png')
        fixed.put(image, 0, 0)
        ####
        text = open('use.txt').read()
        label = gtk.Label(text)
        fixed.put(label, 300, 750)
        self.add(fixed)
        fixed.show_all()
        ####
        self.connect('delete-event', lambda w, e: gtk.main_quit())

TuxWindow().present()
gtk.main()
```